# How do I install mysqli_ for PHP on Linux without affecting anything else?

Tags: linux, mysql, php, installation

I have root access to a server and it is currently running a live e-commerce site with lots of sales. The site currently uses mysql_ for everything. mysqli_ is not installed at all.

I need to keep mysql_ working and every other setting the same so that the site keeps running. How do I simply install mysqli_ on top of all this without changing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the same way you would do other changes.

Test first in a dev test environment, proving the site still functions. Then take a server out of the production load balancer and update.

Regarding mysqli specifically, you may want to understand why you don't have this already. For EL distros, mysqli and pdo have been in the CentOS 5 php-mysql package, early in PHP 5's life.